# Communication between <input type = "submit"> and php

Tags: php, html, forms

Please refer to the image. I want the value of the button pressed which is the id of the student in the database. How do I know which button is pressed by the user?
The problem is that name of all the inputs is same.

```
                <form method="post" name="data">
                    <table style="overflow-x: auto; display: block; white-space: nowrap; max-height: 450px; max-width: 1100px;"
                           class="table table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>

                            <th>Student Name</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Contact No.</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th colspan="4">Accept / Reject</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        $query = "SELECT StudentID,StudentName,Address,ContactNo,Email FROM Student WHERE Accepted=0";
                        $mysqli = connect();
                        //Get result
                        $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error . " " . __LINE__); //__LINE__ shows the line no. we are getting the error at

                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            //Loop through results
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                //Display customer info
                                $output = "<tr>";
                                $output .= "<td>" . $row['StudentID'] . "</td>";

                                $output .= "<td>" . $row['StudentName'] . "</td>";
                                $output .= "<td >" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
                                $output .= "<td >" . $row['ContactNo'] . "</td>";
                                $output .= "<td >" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";

                                $output .= "<td><input type='hidden'  name='Yes" . $row['StudentID'] . "' value='" . $row['StudentID'] . "' ></td>";
                                $output .= "<td><input type='submit'   value='yes' class='btn-success' style='border:none;'></td>";

                                $output .= "<td><input type='hidden'  name='No' value='" . $row['StudentID'] . "' ></td>";
                                $output .= "<td><input type='submit'  value='No' class='btn-link' style='border:none;' ></td>";;
                                $output .= "</tr>";
                                echo $output;
                            }
                            echo "</table>";

                        } else
                            echo "No pending request found";

                        ?>
                    </table>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll have multiple submit buttons (one per each loop of the `foreach`) all you'd need is to pass a unique `value` for the button to identify which one you pressed. One simple way to do it is to pass both the yes/no answer and the studentID. For instance:

```
<input type="submit" name="response" value="yes|<?php echo $row['studentID']; ?>" class="btn-success" style="border:none;">
```

Then, when processing the form you take the value received in `$_POST['response']`, explode it at the pipe and you get the yes/no answer and the student ID:

```
$verdict = explode("|", $_POST['response']);
$yay_or_nay = $verdict[0];
$whom = $verdict[1];
```

then you can do whatever it is that you need to do with `$yay_or_nay` and `$whom`

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that name of all the inputs is same.

Give them unique values, and use a `<button>` element so that the display label is not the same as the value.

```
<button type='submit' value='No-UNIQUE-ID' class='btn-link' style='border:none;'>
    No
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

I actually had a similar issue. The way I solved it was by having two radio buttons on each row with the "yes" or "no" part stored in the value. They are separated by a delimiter from the other value (your StudentID). A submit button below the table then lets the user submit the responses in bulk.

Your code would look something like this:

```
                <form method="post" name="data">
                <table style="overflow-x: auto; display: block; white-space: nowrap; max-height: 450px; max-width: 1100px;"
                       class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>

                        <th>Student Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Contact No.</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th colspan="4">Accept / Reject</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $query = "SELECT StudentID,StudentName,Address,ContactNo,Email FROM Student WHERE Accepted=0";
                    $mysqli = connect();
                    //Get result
                    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error . " " . __LINE__); //__LINE__ shows the line no. we are getting the error at

                    $count = $result->num_rows;
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        //Loop through results
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            //Display customer info
                            $output = "<tr>";
                            $output .= "<td>" . $row['StudentID'] . "</td>";

                            $output .= "<td>" . $row['StudentName'] . "</td>";
                            $output .= "<td >" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
                            $output .= "<td >" . $row['ContactNo'] . "</td>";
                            $output .= "<td >" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";

                            $output .= "<td><input type='radio'  name='radio" . $count . "' value='" . $row['StudentID'] . "|accept' ></td>";

                            $output .= "<td><input type='radio'  name='radio" . $count . "' value='" . $row['StudentID'] . "|reject' ></td>";

                            $output .= "</tr>";
                            echo $output;
                            $count += 1;
                        }
                        echo "</table>";
                        echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>";

                    } else
                        echo "No pending request found";

                    ?>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Then you get the values from whatever radio btn was selected and do the rest of your code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
        if(isset($_POST['radio' . $x])) {
            $values = explode('|', $_POST['radio' . $x]);
            $id = $values[0];
            $status = $values[1];

            //Do stuff with each result
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and had to use JS/jQuery

```
$(".myClass").bind("click", function() {
    var id = event.target.id;
    window.location.href = "myPage?id="+id;
});
```